# HTTP and HTTPS detection in java

Tags: java, http, https

I have a small program that asks a user to enter the URL in form of http://www.cnn.com (they need to type in http//: or https//:) and it will retrieve all the content of that website and print out to console.
My question is that if the user does not know the url they enter is correct for http or https and my program need to handle that error.  For example, cnn.com is https://www.cnn.com but user mistakenly enters http://www.cnn.com then there is nothing printed to console because of an 's' follow the 'http'.  So how can I handle this error?  Same for some websites start with 'https' but user enters 'http'.
Sorry for my poor English, any helps will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
class url2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
  String url;
  System.out.println("Enter the URL: ");
  BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new
  InputStreamReader(System.in));
  url=f.readLine();
  URL yahoo = new URL(url);
  URLConnection yahoo1=yahoo.openConnection();
  BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new
  InputStreamReader(yahoo1.getInputStream()));
  String inputLine;

  while ((inputLine = dis.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
  }
  dis.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException me) {
  System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + me);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Most websites will auto-redirect from http to https if the latter is supported.  cnn.com is a great example of such.

Comment: You should share your code because then we can figure out why your program isn't handling the redirect correctly.

Comment: Check for an HTTP redirect status in the initial response.  If present, call your method again with the new URL.

Comment: I would say the best approach is to handle redirect like Andrew said, if you are using HttpClient it already does that for you by default. But else you should just tell your users that there was no response from the server.

Comment: are there any ways to tell the url is http or https?  Say that if the user enter http//:www.cnn.com my program will fix the url to be https://www.cnn.com

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to try open a connection to a specific port: 80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS. If the port is closed, there is no HTTP/HTTPS support.

Code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
try {
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("cnn.com", 80), 3000);
    // read one byte to make sure
    socket.getInputStream().read();
    // we've connected successfully, there is http:// support!
} catch (ConnectException e) {
    // the port is probably closed, no http:// here
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // either port is not open, or the network is slow
} finally {
    socket.close();
}
```

This probes port 80. If the connection is established successfully, you can be sure that there **is** something on port 80 (http port). But if a timeout happens (here I set 3 seconds for timeout), this can either mean that the port is not open (and there is no http), or there is some problem with the network connection, probably a transient one.

So this method is not too reliable, although for 'good' sites you can expect to be accessible with low latency.